# Renovate and expose old/cracked wood posts, rafters and ties

Tags: wood, woodworking, beam

I am planning on exposing three wood posts/rafters in our living room. At the moment, these have been covered by wood panels and plasterboard.
I have started looking behind and realised that the posts present various cracks and look very coarse.

**Wood:**
I am not expecting to have a perfectly smooth result, but I would like to smooth out the splinters, smooth the cracks and apply a stain, oil or varnish. See pictures attached.

**Ties:**
Between one of the beams and rafters, there are two metal tension rods that have been bolted on to tie them: one towards the top and one towards the bottom (see red lines in attached pic). Right now, they are covered by plasterboard which I would remove, but I can see that these rods are not suitable for being exposed as the metal has sharp edges and they have been installed at a clumsy angle. They would have to be replaced.

**Questions**

1. What type of cleaning techniques for the wood would you suggest? E.g. wire brush, orbital sanding
2. What type of filler could be used to fill the cracks and finishing layer? E.g. Epoxy?
3. As an alternative to the metal rods (wife does not like metal to be visible), could wood be used for the ties? Though, there would be an aesthetical issue of wood colours would not match

[image: Cracked and splintered wood post]

[image: Wooden posts]

Comment: Would be careful with changing any support ties there.  It looks like it might be more structural than decorative.  My opinion is that you should work with what is in second/bottom picture.  Sand and stain/paint the wood boxes.  Think it would look nice with a light wood stain.  If do not want plaster, can change it to a nice plywood/wood covering.

Comment: It appears that you've got rough framing, some covered in drywall, some covered with wood (veneer). Your goal is to remove all the drywall and veneer leaving only the rough framing? I would be _very_ cautious about removing material from the framing itself as anything you remove reduces the amount of wood holding up your upper floor/roof.